# Synonymous request: [IPL] and [Indian-premier-league]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-synonyms

Currently there are 6 questions tagged with [ipl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipl) while [one question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1604/540) was tagged with [indian-premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-premier-league) which I re-tagged with [ipl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipl) since the meaning of both tag is same. So should we make [indian-premier-league](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-premier-league) tag a of synonymous of [ipl](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipl)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sports have the same `IPL` acronym:

- Indian Premier League, a cricket league in India
- Indonesian Premier League, a football league
- Iran Pro League, a football league
- Irish Premier League, a former football league
- Israeli Premier League, a football league

So, I would say no to this particular request. I would, in fact, merge `IPL` to `indian-premier-league` without synonymization to further distinguish. Mind you, there are other premier leagues as tags: [`english-premier-league`](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-premier-league)

Comment: True enough. Thanks.